# What's the proper way to generate 6 characters alphanumeric code in which sum of all characters equals 9? (Voucher code generator)

Tags: c#, random, alphanumeric

My first idea was to make an array/list that has values assigned to each character.
So for example:

array[0] =' 0'

array[10] = 'A'

[...]

Then code would pick a random number y between [0,x] for slot 1.
For next slot [0,(x-y)] etc. When y <= 0 then fill rest of the slots with '0'.

Would that be enough for a simple voucher code generator? (It's not my decision to make encryption with this rule)

I am worried that sum of 9 is quite low for 6 character code, letters won't be used at all since they all have value over 9.
To prevent situation like this:
540000, 630000, 180000
Should I make chance of '0' to appear more?

What do you guys think about it?
Maybe you could also suggest some other way of doing this.

@Edit

Examples:

112320 = 1+1+2+3+2+0 = 9  Valid code, sum equals 9

000900 = 0+0+0+9+0+0 = 9 Valid code, sum equals 9

003015 = 0+0+3+0+1+5 = 9 Valid code, sum equals 9

A0012B = 10+0+0+1+2+11 = 24 Invalid code

Comment: Could you please share a spec for this kind of serial number. It's not clear from your words how it should look

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko I added some examples in edit, if its still not clear could you elaborate what I should include to make it easier to understand?

Comment: What would be the value of A in your case? If that is 10, you are already above the limit. Unless you take the full value (however you calculate that) and that mustbe *divisible* by 9

Comment: @HansKeﬆing
I know that A and other letters are over limit this is why I have some doubts, I got this rule ' 6 characters alphanumeric code in which sum of all characters equals 9' laid to me by client.
I am making game for mobile devices, afterwards code is generated based on this rule. Data base, verification, marking code as used etc is client's responsibility.

Comment: Then you can at least forget about the "alpha" part - that code has to be numeric-only

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes it seems confusing, maybe they meant that code is supposed to be alphanumeric but only the digits are summed up? So ABC081 = 0+0+0+0+8+1=9? I would have to confirm on Monday. I think this way it makes a little more sense, what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that the function `Rand(n)` creates a random integer number that can go from `0` up to `n` (`n` included), then you can do the following:

```
Sum = 0;
A[0] = Rand(9);
Sum += A[0];
A[1] = Rand(9 - Sum);
Sum += A[1];
A[2] = Rand(9 - Sum);
Sum += A[2];
...
```

I just wrote this down very quickly, I didn't check the boundaries, but such an algorithm should do the trick.